# Texture Paint - Material Bump is pixelated

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting, bump

I am trying to paint a texture but I encounter difficulties when I use Material bump, the bump looks pixelated, how to fix that?

I tried to increase the resolution (2048x2048 or 4096x4096...) of the texture, but there is no difference.
[image]

[image]
Also, here is an example (not the original) of the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GX30KkplO8cjmk53oUR2M5V1ZwzrWe2j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The resolution of your texture seems to be too low ? When you create the texture (Image/New...), you can choose the resolution, which by default- is 1024x1024.Try something way bigger, like 4096x4096

Comment: I tried with your blend, and increasing the resolution definitively make a difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand with b&w drawings and bump maps:

- It needs to be PNG or EXR, not JPG
- It needs to be *16-Bit Float* or *32-Bit Float*, not *8-Bit* (if you paint it while *8-Bit*, switch to *16-Bit Float* or *32-Bit Float* and blur or repaint)
- It needs a high enough resolution (maybe increase it)
- Enable *Cubic* instead of Linear in the Image Texture:

[image]

Comment: Wow, cubic interpolation seems to give really good results in that situation. I need to dig that deeper... Thanks Moonbots for the tip!

Comment: @ thibsert, still not perfect though, I think it used to work better, I hope they will fix it